# Is there a way to share a ViewModel between a Page and a child user control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I am working on a Silverlight navigation project.  `MainPage` contains a navigation frame.  Inside the navigation frame, my first page is called `LiveView`.  `LiveView.xaml` contains a user control `NavigationControl`.  I'm unsure if I am utilizing MVVM correctly here.

Let's say `LiveView` uses the view model `LayoutsViewModel`.  The `LayoutsViewModel` applies to elements in both `LiveView` and the user control `NavigationControl`.  How do I "share" this view model between `LiveView` and `NavigationControl`?  Is that even the correct approach?

Currently, I set the `LayoutsViewModel` property of `LiveView` to an instance of `LayoutsViewModel`.  Then, I set the `DataContext` of `NavigationControl` to this same instance of `LayoutsviewModel`, like so:

```
LayoutsViewModel = new LayoutsViewModel();
NavigationControl.DataContext = LayoutsViewModel;
```

This way, I can access the `LayoutsViewModel` in `LiveView` via this property and I can access the `LayoutsViewModel` in `NavigationControl` via `DataContext as LayoutsViewModel`.  This seems wrong to me, but it works.

Is there a way to share a view model between a page and a child user control?  Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Treat your UserControl like any other control.  How do you bind text in your ViewModel to a TextBox?  You bind to a public property on the TB called Text.  But have you ever seen the template for a TextBox?  It's very complex.  The xaml and codebehind of the TextBox wires things together.  Expose properties on the surface of your NavigationControl and bind them to your VM.  Done.

Comment: @Will, thanks for the comment.  So what about this: I have a button in `NavigationControl` that should add a new item to an `ObservableCollection` in the `LayoutsViewModel`.  How do I communicate from `NavigationControl` to `LayoutsViewModel` that a new object should be added to the collection and saved to my configuration JSON?

Comment: There are a number of ways.  Not sure which is best for your design.  But, if you treated it like any control, you'd expose a RoutedEvent on the UC and bind an ICommand to that (there's lots of ways to do that as well).

Comment: Thanks, @Will, you have been very helpful.